# Invalid Domain error in Email Settings API

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, google-email-settings-api

I tried to create labels in my personal Gmail Account using **Email Settings API**.

I have sent http post reqeust to the below URL

https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/gmail.com/username/label

but am getting **invalid domain (403)** error.

is it possible to change the settings for personal Gmail account using Email Settings API?

if yes means what should I do?

Is there any other way to create new Label in Gmail personal account?

pls help on this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email settings is part of the Admin SDK and is only available to Google Apps domains, nothing available for gmail.com to do this kind of thing presently.

Answer (score 1):

Eric's answer is correct, you can't modify email settings of a @gmail.com account like page size, delegation and imap/pop on/off.

Though if all you want to do is create labels, you can use the Gmail API with @gmail.com accounts. See the [labels.create()](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/create) function.